# How to draw a 1/4 of a circle in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using Python 3.7.4 and Pygame 1.9.6. I know about the `pygame.draw.arc` and `pygame.draw.circle`. I want to draw a quarter circle like here: [image]

It's the quarter circle of the soccer field.

My attempts:

```
pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255, 255, 255), (75, 25, 50, 50), 90, 120, 5)
```

[image]

```
pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255, 255, 255), (75, 25, 50, 50), 80, 100, 5)
```

Changing the starting angle and ending angle doesn't change a thing it seems.

[image]

So it must be the coordinates of drawing the boundaries.
When I change the 75 in this`(75, 25, 50, 50)` it just makes the circle go to the right more. If the change the 25 in `(75, 25, 50, 50)` it makes it go up or down more. If I change the first 50 in `(75, 25, 50, 50)` it makes it wider width bigger or smaller depending on changing the numbers. If I change the second 50 in `(75, 25, 50, 50)` it makes the height bigger or smaller.
I've just tried decimals in the angles, because the coordinates have to be integers. When I do `pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255, 255, 255), (75, 25, 100, 50), 95.5, 100.5, 5)` look at the decimals.

I get:

[image]

So maybe the key it changing the starting and ending angles I'll keep updating what I find.
I found the right one with help from @bashBedlam in the comments:

```
pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255, 255, 255), (60, 13, 50, 50), 17, 13, 5)
```

[image]

I changed the coordinates but keep the same starting and ending angle.
Which is pretty much perfect though I do hate the little black dots though.
The screen is `600 x 600`
I can't get to right angle or the circle itself. I'm not aloud to use decimals. Only allows integers. So I don't know how to properly make a quarter circle. I appreciate the advice and thanks.

I just wanted to say for people helping me I've created my own soccer field. I drew all the lines out, but then I just turned it into a png so it wouldn't lag me out of loading all 27 lines with the background constantly. Here is the finished result with everyone's help:
[image]

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
What *do* you get with your `arc` call, and why are your other experiments not working?

Comment: Can you show what your attempt looks like? I noticed you have the angles as `90, 120`, which is probably the issue because it needs to be a floating point value in radians. You mention `I'm not allowed to use decimals` - is that a self-imposed restriction, a homework criteria, or a mistaken assumption about the `draw.arc` arguments?

Comment: Try : `pygame.draw.arc (screen, (255, 255, 255), (75, 25, 50, 50), 17, 13, 5)`

Comment: @bashBedlam That's literally like almost perfect I just need to change the coordinates and maybe the angles a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `pygame.draw.arc` takes angles in radians as stated in the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.arc). Also angles between 90 and 120 would not draw and arc like you need, 90 to -90 will.

```
import pygame
import math
pygame.init()

d = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))

while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    d.fill((255, 255, 255))

    pygame.draw.arc(d, (0, 0, 0), [900, 300, 100, 100], math.radians(90), math.radians(-90), 5)
    pygame.draw.arc(d, (0, 0, 0), [300, 300, 100, 100], math.radians(-90), math.radians(90), 5)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Edit:

So i was looking online for ways for pygame.draw.arc to draw arc without dots without using floating point numbers, but couldn't any, so i wrote this function for you. If you consider this function as not being a part of the code you wrote (like pygame.draw.arc) then technically, you are not using decimal because the decimal is only used inside of the function(finessed the system :)). Here's the function:

```
def drawArc(display, startAngle, endAngle, distance, pos, color, thickness=1):
    if startAngle > endAngle:
        theta = endAngle
        bigger = startAngle
    else:
        theta = startAngle
        bigger = endAngle
        
    while theta < bigger: 
        for t in range(thickness):
            x = round((cos(radians(theta)) * (distance-t)) + pos[0])
            y = round((-sin(radians(theta)) * (distance-t)) + pos[1])
            display.set_at((x, y), color)
            theta += 0.01
```

Think of this function like a compass, it draws an arc in-between the angle you specify (in degrees). Argument `pos` being the centre of the compass and `distance` being the distance of the arc from the centre. So now just draw the quarter circles in 4 different corners.

```
import pygame
from math import radians, sin, cos
pygame.init()

d = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))

def drawArc(display, startAngle, endAngle, distance, pos, color, thickness=1):
    if startAngle > endAngle:
        theta = endAngle
        bigger = startAngle
    else:
        theta = startAngle
        bigger = endAngle
        
    while theta < bigger: 
        for t in range(thickness):
            x = round((cos(radians(theta)) * (distance-t)) + pos[0])
            y = round((-sin(radians(theta)) * (distance-t)) + pos[1])
            display.set_at((x, y), color)
            theta += 0.01
    
        
while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    d.fill((255, 255, 255))

    drawArc(d, -90, 0, 100, [0, 0], (0, 0, 0), thickness=5)
    drawArc(d, 180, 270, 100, [1200, 0], (0, 0, 0), thickness=5)
    drawArc(d, 0, 90, 100, [0, 600], (0, 0, 0), thickness=5)
    drawArc(d, 180, 90, 100, [1200, 600], (0, 0, 0), thickness=5)
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Btw, using this function hinders performance, so i strongly recommend using `pygame.draw.arc` with floating point numbers if possible.

Comment: Thank you for doing this man I appreciate it. I will definitely use this.